# I have Ubuntu and Windows 10 installed on 2 different drives. How do I remove Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mbr

I found an old SSD and decided to use it for Ubuntu on my desktop where I only had Windows 10. I installed it and everything worked fine (dual booting, that is). Turns out that the reason the SSD was lying around was because it was broken.

So I figured that I would just remove the SSD and proceed with only Windows 10 but when I remove the SSD, I can't boot at all. I get into some sort of grub rescue environment.

As they were on different hard drives, I don't understand how I could mess up the Windows 10 SSD mbr?

Any suggestions for how to get out of this?

**tl;dr** Ubuntu on one SSD, Windows 10 on one SSD. I want to physically remove the Ubuntu SSD and only run W10. How?

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure because ubuntu overwrites windows boot manager.

Partition or disk is the same thing, you must introduce a windows 10 CD / USB and boot it.

You can download the .iso here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Burn it on a CD/DVD or use rufus for a USB

Once you booted the windows disk/usb go to repair option, select advanced options and then command prompt and type this

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /rebuildbcd
exit
```

Reboot and it will run windows, if you want to erase the ssd just go to windows partition manager and erase all the ssd.